# What version of iOS stopped asking for Apple ID verification on calling "restoreCompletedTransactions"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore, storekit

When I first developed an inapp purchase solution for an iOS app, one of the annoying things was that calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` would ask the user to verify their Apple ID every time, popping up the dreaded password dialog. I was testing this against iOS 8 & 9.

Skip forward a few years and now I have noticed that on iOS 12.1, calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` doesn't show that dialog unless the user has signed out of their Apple account under Settings.

So I'm wondering, what version of iOS stopped showing this dialog on every call to that function?

I wish I had a pile of iOS test devices with all the old versions, but unfortunately I only have devices running iOS 12 so I can't test this out myself.

The reason I want to know is because being able to call that method without invoking the stupid dialog means I can potentially use it as a background method of checking what purchases a user has made on starting/resuming the app.
Once I know which iOS version stopped asking for Apple ID verification on every call to restore, I can add some conditional logic to only do this on or above that iOS version.

I have an app where non-consumable inapp purchases allow content packages to be downloaded to the device. 
Users often use my app across their iOS devices and so currently they have to manually sync the purchased content between devices using the "Restore purchases" button.
However, if I can call `restoreCompletedTransactions` in the background to obtain a list of their owned non-consumable purchases, I can diff that against the content packages already downloaded to their device and therefore automatically restore content packages for purchases they've made on other devices. 
This is something I've been able to do on Android for ages and users ask why the app can't do the same on iOS.

(BTW I know the way of doing this recommended by Apple is to store the receipt of purchase from Apple on my server and use this to verify re-downloading of content, but for various reasons this was not possible)

Comment: Is there documentation stating that iOS 12 doesn't show that dialog unless the user has signed out of their Apple account under Settings? I think I recall still seen the dialog even though I'm signed in.

Comment: No such documentation exists detailing the conditions under which the dialog is presented. This is purely the result of empirical observation.